# Regex to get just everything in CAPS

Tags: regex, perl, split

I am looking for a regex to get just about the words in CAPS

for eg : I have an array that is storing the file paths and these could be in any following pattern

```
images/p/n/ct/XYZ-WW_V1.jpg

images/p/c/ABC-TY_V2.jpg
```

So basically I want just "XYZ-WW" and "ABC-TY" .
Any suggestions what regex to use in my split code . I am using the following

```
foreach (@filefound){

my @result = split('_',$_);

push @split1, $result[0];

}
```

This is just splitting at the _ and I am accessing the [0] the value but now I want to get just the part that is in CAPS .

Any Suggestions please !!

Comment: please learn how to format your code here

Comment: What do you want if you have a path like `images/P/n/ABC-4b.jpg`?  Are you really asking to strip off the path and extension and return only the filename?

Comment: @Jim : The File names have the format of "CAPS-CAPS_V1.jpg" . I just need the portion of CAPS-CAPS like TRWE-SD162

Comment: @ysth : Honestly I know I suck at this but I will learn !! thanks for making me realize.

Comment: Is it just capital letters, and is the format exact? how many capital letters and are any of them numbers, is it then also a V and a single digit number followed by a .jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this should work:

```
[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+
```

Comment: The part after hyphen might also have number so would 
[A-Z]+-[A-Z][0-9]+ work ?

Comment: Well that would force a number.  So you would want something like this...

[A-Z]+-([0-9]*)[A-Z]+([0-9]*)

If you don't need to support the prefix number, just remove the first ([0-9]*)

Comment: The difference between * and + is * is 0 or more occurrences and + is 1 or more occurrences.  So if you have a repeating string and it's not required, use *.  If it's required, use +.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to use `split` at all.  Just grab the bits you want via a regular expression.  From your example, it looks like you want everything which is made of capital ASCII letters and dashes:

```
my @bignames;
foreach (@filefound){
    if ( /([A-Z-]+)/ ) {
        push @bignames, $1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use @bigname instead and that will populate the array with all the matches ?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I changed it to gather all of the names into an array called `bignames`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (@filefound) {
   if ($_ ~= /.*([A-Z]+-[A-Z]+)_[A-Z]\d\..{3}$ ) {
      push @split1, $1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if ($_ =~ /[\-A-Z]+/)
    push @split1, $&;
```

that will match any combination of uppercase letters and -; or, if you want a stricter control, this:

```
if ($_ =~ /\/([A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{2})_/)
    push @split1, $1;
```

which will match only a sequence of uppercase letters followed by `-` and by a sequence of 2 uppercase letters; starting with a `/` and ending in `_` (those are excluded).

From these example you can build the exact regex that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a match in list context will return captured strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;
use File::Basename qw(basename);

my @files = qw(
    images/p/n/ct/XYZ-WW_V1.jpg
    images/p/c/ABC-TY_V2.jpg
);

my @prefixes = map { (basename $_) =~ /^( [A-Z]+ - [A-Z]+ )/x } @files;

print "$_\n" for @prefixes;
```